# Find $\int \sqrt{ \sec^4 x + \cos^4 x}dx$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

Find $\int \sqrt{ \sec^4 x + \cos^4 x} dx$

I tried by taking $\sec^2 x $out of the square root and taking $\cos^2 x $ out of the root, but all my effort goes in vain. So anybody please helps me. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you get this question? It is possible that this function may not have an elementary anti-derivative (Wolfram doesn't give an answer)

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг actually this problem came out during a group discussion with friends.

Comment: I would recommend finding the Taylor series and integrating that.

Comment: fair enough , but the problem is that such problems are not necessarily solvable. this one is likely to be in. such a category.

Comment: To reiterate @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг's point, you can attempt to use the substitution $$u = \cos x, du = -\sin x dx = -\sqrt{1-u^2}dx \Longrightarrow dx = -\dfrac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}$$ Plugging in, you get: $$-\int \sqrt{ \dfrac{1+u^8}{u^4-u^6} }du$$ and plugging this into Wolframalpha does give an answer: [(no result found in terms of standard mathematical functions)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Int%5BSqrt%5B%281%2Bu%5E8%29%2F%28u%5E4-u%5E6%29%5D%2Cu%5D)

Comment: Thanks gentlemen for your precious advises.